# OneDrive API integration with Unity 3D

Tags: c#, api, unity-game-engine, onedrive, fileshare

I would like to know if it is possible to integrate the OneDrive API directly with Unity 3D. I am trying to upload image files to an OneDrive account using C#, yet Microsoft's documentation does not mention how to achieve this.

Comment: Please provide code examples to show want you have tried. Also describe what exactly does not work, like thrown errors, error message. In addition to that add the versions of frameworks and API you use. All this details will help us to help you.

Comment: The idea for my application is to take pictures of a user and store them into an OneDrive account as part of a research project. I am using Unity3D for this purpose as one of the requirements for the application is to be cross-platform (Android and iOS). I have also used [plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/HolographicAcademy/raw/Azure-MixedReality-Labs/Azure%20Mixed%20Reality%20Labs/MR%20and%20Azure%20311%20-%20Microsoft%20Graph/MSGraph_LabPlugins.unitypackage) For this application I am trying to upload files to OneDrive without the user having to login to their account. @developer10214

Answer (score 0):

One drive only provides [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/onedrive/developer/rest-api/?view=odsp-graph-online) which you can use with [Web Requests](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-SendingForm.html)

Assuming you are logged in and you have a session token and key and OneDrive URL from API you can use PUT request:
`PUT /drives/{drive-id}/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content` to upload image

```
void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(Upload());
}

IEnumerator Upload() {
    byte[] myData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is some test data");
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Put("ttps://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content", myData);
    //add to www object all header data with session token and content type
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else {
        Debug.Log("Upload complete!");
    }
}
```

You can also try community made C# plugins for that like this one: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp but they did not publish a change for a 3 years now, so it might now work anymore

Comment: I have created a new application using Microsoft Azure in order to access the OneDrive account through Unity. Once I created the new application I stored the application ID as well as a token that I created. How could I implement this with the www request? I also wanted to add that for the purpose of this application the user would not log in (at least not knowingly), the application would send data from the device and store it in a OneDrive account (similar functionality to a server).

Comment: @CostinGrigore were able to solve this issue? If so do you mind sharing your answer?

Comment: @Mad Unfortunately, after getting in touch with Microsoft, they have informed me that currently there is no solution for this issue. The technology exists for doing it, yet they haven't documented it to be used by the public. At the moment the only thing that they allow is accessing Microsoft account using the Microsoft Authenticator process.